# sbt cannot switch to project imported from github using ProjectRef

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

I have an sbt (Play) applicaiton which needs to depend on another sbt(play) multi-module application. I imported that using `ProjectRef`, my local application's `build.sbt` as follows

```
lazy val aaaroot = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/abcd/abcd.git"), "aaaroot")
lazy val core = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.comabcd/abcd.git"), "core")
lazy val zeusEvolutions = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/abcd/abcd.git"), "zeusEvolutions")

lazy val aaaaaaaroot = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(aaaroot, core, zeusEvolutions).aggregate(aaaroot, core, zeusEvolutions)
```

SBT console showing the projects are imported properly like

```
[play-multiple] $ projects
[info] In file:/Users/RP/LeanTaaS/play-multiple/
[info]   * aaaaaaaroot
[info] In https://github.com/abcd/abcd.git
[info]     aaaroot
[info]     core
[info]     zeusEvolutions
```

However I switch to a project which is imported from github, it is saying `Not a valid project`.

```
[play-multiple] $ project aaaroot
[error] Not a valid project ID: aaaroot (similar: aaaaaaaroot)
[error] project aaaroot
[error]                ^
[play-multiple] $ project core
[error] Not a valid project ID: core
[error] project core
[error]             ^
```

This is my one of issues, the actual issue is when I refer my application routes to the imported project's routes, it is not able to find them. I am thinking this issue could the root cause of the actual issue.

Could somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that you can not switch to a project using `project <project_id>` unless it is a `Project`. http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html#General+commands

I was able to resolve my actual problem (referencing a Play application in another play application) by declaring my child application as sub-project within a dummy root project. Not sure what is the exact reason, but after many attempts and source code debugging, this approach was working

Now my build looks like,

```
lazy val aaaroot = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/abcd/abcd.git"), "aaaroot")
lazy val core = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.comabcd/abcd.git"), "core")
lazy val zeusEvolutions = ProjectRef(uri("https://github.com/abcd/abcd.git"), "zeusEvolutions")

lazy val aaaaaaaroot = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(aaaapp, aaaroot, core, zeusEvolutions).aggregate(aaaapp, aaaroot, core, zeusEvolutions)

lazy val aaaapp = (project in file("modules/play-multiple)......
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
[play-multiple] $ project {file:/Users/RP/LeanTaaS/play-multiple/aaaroot}
```

You'll also get tab completion here. E.g., type `project {`, then `<TAB>`.

It's not pretty, but it works.